# Form Validation in CakePHP 2

Tags: php, forms, validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

## In my view I have

```
<?= $this->Form->create('Asc201516', array(
'url' => array(
    'controller' => 'asc201516s', 
    'action'     => 'submit_asc201516'
    ), 
'class' => 'form-inline',
'onsubmit' => 'return check_minteacher()'
)); ?>

<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <?= $this->Form->input('bi_school_na', array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'onkeypress' => 'return isNumberKey(event)',
        'label'       => 'NA', 
        'placeholder' => 'NA', 
        'class'       => 'form-control'
    )); ?>
</div>
<?php 
$options = array(
    'label' => 'Submit',
    'class' => 'btn btn-primary');
echo $this->Form->end($options); 
?>
```

## In my Controller, I have

```
$this->Asc201516->set($this->request->data['Asc201516']);
        if ($this->Asc201516->validates()) {
            echo 'it validated logic';
            exit();

        } else {                
            $this->redirect(
                array(
                    'controller' => 'asc201516s',
                    'action' => 'add', $semisid
                    )
                );

        }
```

## In my Model, I have

```
 public $validate = array(
        'bi_school_na' => array(
            'Numeric' => array(
                'rule' => 'Numeric',
                'required' => true,
                'message' => 'numbers only',
                'allowEmpty' => false
            )
        )
    );
```

When I submit the form, logically it should not get submitted and print out the error message but the form gets submitted instead and validates the model inside controller which breaks the operation in controller.

Comment: in your controller in this action you have only `$school = $this->Asc201516->save($this->request->data);`?

Comment: Actually it does validate the data but doesn't show errors in view. I am also using CakePHP form helper. When validation fails it just loads the view but doesn't show errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check validation in your controller like

```
$this->Asc201516->set($this->request->data);  
if($this->Asc201516->validates()){  
    $this->Asc201516->save($this->request->data);  
}else{  
    $this->set("semisid",$semisid);
    $this->render("Asc201516s/add");
}
```

You will have your `ID` there in variable `$semisid`, or you can set data in   `$this->request->data = $this->Asc201516->findById($semisid);`

Comment: if validates() returns false then in our else condition it should go to the view and display errors, right? It's just redirecting to the view but not displaying errors. How would the end user know what the error was or which input did he put wrong.

Comment: @Pallew confirm you have not written `unset($this->request->data)` in your code. and using `$this->Form->input()` for creating input. or you have to show error manually by writing `$this->Form->error()`. See [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::error)

Comment: No, I don't have that unset statement in my code. Documentation says that "When using FormHelper::input(), errors are rendered by default". My validation() returns false and gets redirected nice and easy but doesn't show/display errors.

Comment: @Pallew Please update your question with action code in controller, so i can understand whats the problem

Comment: I see, you shouldn't redirect,instead just put flash message in else condition and render the view only, error messages will be there

Comment: Thanks @AIPD TECH. You're right, it's being displayed in default view of action i.e. "submit_201516.ctp" but my form is placed in different view with record ID as parameter to fetch it details and display the form. Any suggestion how can I preserve errors and form values whilst redirecting the user back to the form to correct the fields?